# An example to illustrate the difference between an inversion operation and a twofold rotation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, symmetry

Reading in Atkin's Inorganic Chemistry book, I cam accross:

> Although an inversion and a twofold rotation may sometimes achieve the
>   same effect, that is not the case in general and the two operations
>   must be distinguished.

He does not give an example of an occasion where such cases are not the same.

I will appreciate if someone can give an example of when inversion and twofold operation won't give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If the body is chiral, a ${C_2}$-axis maintains chirality.  An inversion (${S_2}$, ${i}$, the product of ${C_2}$ and ${σ}$h) inverts chirality.

https://ww2.chemistry.gatech.edu/~wilkinson/Class_notes/CHEM_3111_6170/Symmetry_and_group_theory.pdf 
Frame 5 
http://alpha.chem.umb.edu/chemistry/ch612/documents/MolecularGeometryandPointGroups_002.pdf 
More technical 
http://www.b-u.ac.in/sde_book/msc_phychem.pdf 
The math

Comment: Of course, chiral objects do *not* have any Sn improper axes of symmetry.  Above describes operation of the transformation .